# Adding OCUnit to excisting project in XCode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am trying to add OCUnit to a excisting XCode project however I am not able to run it. The "Test" row in the "Product" menu is gray after following this [guide](http://twobitlabs.com/2011/06/adding-ocunit-to-an-existing-ios-project-with-xcode-4/). Anyone having another tutorial or know how to that? Or other solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to edit the scheme for the application target to enable the Test item in the Product menu. To open the scheme editor, click on the Scheme menu in the project window toolbar and choose Edit Scheme. Select the Test step on the left side of the scheme editor. The list of tests should be empty. Click the + button to open a target sheet. Select the unit testing target from the list and click the Add button.